# MySQL problems on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I just erased and re-installed Snow Leopard. I installed MySQL 5.1.48 64-bit clean. I'm having issues with the MySQL server... when I boot the computer and log in, the server is not running. I tried to start it using the preference pane by clicking "Start MySQL Server", but all it did was highlight the button blue and think for like a minute, and then the button went back to normal and nothing happened.

I then tried starting it from the terminal:

```
    Hristo$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
    Starting MySQL
    ....................................................................................................
    ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

so I checked the status:

```
Hristo$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status
Password:
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: line 418: pidof: command not found
 ERROR! MySQL is not running
```

I tried this:

```
Hristo$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So I'm not sure what to do. Earlier today, the server was working but I went to the preference pane to try and stop it… and the same thing happened… I clicked the "Stop MysQL Server" button, it did some thinking, then nothing. So I restarted the computer and now I'm having the above problems and apparently, the mysql.sock file is not in /tmp/ anymore… it was earlier today.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Hristo

UPDATE 2: error log file:

```
100701 13:27:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
100701 13:27:03 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
100701 13:27:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
100701 13:27:03  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
```

This repeats for a while and then...

```
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
100701 13:28:43  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
100701 13:28:43  InnoDB: Operating system error number 35 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 35 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
100701 13:28:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
100701 13:28:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
100701 13:28:43 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
100701 13:28:43 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
100701 13:28:43 [ERROR] Aborting

100701 13:28:43 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

100701 13:28:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid ended
```

UPDATE: after trying to start MySQL with `sudo sh -x`

```
Hristo$ sudo sh -x /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
+ basedir=
+ datadir=
+ service_startup_timeout=900
+ pid_file=
+ server_pid_file=
+ use_mysqld_safe=1
+ user=mysql
+ test -z ''
+ basedir=/usr/local/mysql
+ bindir=./bin
+ test -z ''
+ datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
+ sbindir=./bin
+ libexecdir=./bin
+ datadir_set=
+ lsb_functions=/lib/lsb/init-functions
+ test -f /lib/lsb/init-functions
+ PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
+ export PATH
+ mode=start
+ shift
+ other_args=
+ case `echo "testing\c"`,`echo -n testing` in
++ echo 'testing\c'
++ echo -n testing
+ echo_n=
+ echo_c='\c'
+ test -x ./bin/my_print_defaults
+ print_defaults=./bin/my_print_defaults
+ extra_args=
+ test -r /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf
+ test -r /usr/local/mysql/data/my.cnf
++ ./bin/my_print_defaults mysqld server mysql_server mysql.server
+ parse_server_arguments
++ ./bin/my_print_defaults manager
+ parse_manager_arguments
+ test -z ''
++ /bin/hostname
+ pid_file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqlmanager-pid_file.pid
+ test -z ''
++ /bin/hostname
+ server_pid_file=/usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ case "$mode" in
+ cd /usr/local/mysql
+ manager=./bin/mysqlmanager
+ test -x ./bin/mysqlmanager
+ manager=./bin/mysqlmanager
+ echo 'Starting MySQL'
Starting MySQL
+ test -x ./bin/mysqlmanager -a 1 = 0
+ test -x ./bin/mysqld_safe
+ pid_file=/usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ wait_for_pid created 23653
+ verb=created
+ manager_pid=23653
+ i=0
+ avoid_race_condition='by checking again'
+ test 0 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ :
+ echo '.\c'
.+ ./bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
++ expr 0 + 1
+ i=1
+ sleep 1
+ test 1 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ :
+ echo '.\c'
.++ expr 1 + 1
+ i=2
+ sleep 1
+ test 2 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ :
```

This repeats for a long time...

```
+ echo '.\c'
.++ expr 97 + 1
+ i=98
+ sleep 1
+ test 98 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ :
+ echo '.\c'
.++ expr 98 + 1
+ i=99
+ sleep 1
+ test 99 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ :
+ echo '.\c'
.++ expr 99 + 1
+ i=100
+ sleep 1
+ test 100 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ test -n 'by checking again'
+ avoid_race_condition=
+ continue
+ test 100 -ne 900
+ case "$verb" in
+ test -s /usr/local/mysql/data/pid_file.pid
+ test -n 23653
+ kill -0 23653
+ test -n ''
+ log_failure_msg 'Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.'
+ echo ' ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.'
 ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
+ return 1
+ return_value=1
+ test -w /var/lock/subsys
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Could you post any logs if you're aware of them? I also looked into that "pidof not found" error. Pidof finds the PID of a process, but I believe it mysql can't find pidof, it ignores it, and tries a different way to check if mysql itself is running. So, I think it might be a permission error when mysql is starting. Any logs that reflect mysql would be great to see.

Comment: I would love to post logs of errors... where would I find them? Also, who should own all of the mysql stuff? My account is an admin account and a lot of things are either owned by root or me. Should mysql be the owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the permissions for the directory where the PID file is to be created (/var/run or what is it)?

It might also be something with wrong options in my.cnf. Try to launch MySQL without my.cnf (rename it) or comment out everything except for the absolutely necessary options.

Comment: my.cnf only has `[client] socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock [mysqld] socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons, there's not nearly enough information in your question for us to determine the cause of your problem with any certainty.

In particular:

How did you install MySQL? Did you use a package? If so, which one? Or did you build from source?

Here are some suggestions:

If you change your start command to:

```
sudo sh -x /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

You'll see every command that the script executes and that will give you (us) help understanding where things are going wrong.

On my OSX 10.5 install, everything under /usr/local/mysql is owned root:wheel **except** /usr/local/mysql/data which is _mysql:wheel. This is probably the most common mysql startup problem.

The error log is likely to be informative and is probably to found at /usr/local/mysql/data/HOSTNAME.err.

That should be enough to enable you to fix things for yourself; if not, answer my question and post your log and we can go from there.

Comment: I installed via the DMG file found on the MySQL Downloads site... specifically Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive. I am running Mac OS X 10.6.4 and the computer is 64-bit. I checked the owners and my setup is the same as yours. Everything is root:wheel except /usr/local/mysql/data which is also _mysql:wheel. The terminal will not let me go inside the `/data/` directory because of permission error. I am root and I used `sudo` and it still won't let me in.

Comment: I pasted the output after running with the `-x` flag

Comment: sudo bash will start a shell that will let you look in /data/.

That error log should tell us what the exact problem is. Also, please verify that the permisions for /data/ are rwxr-w---

Comment: the permissions for `/data/` is rwxr-x--- and the owners are _mysql:wheel. I will post above from the error log.

Comment: sounds like you have a process already running that has port 3306 open and data/ibdata1 locked.

Verify that you don't have a mysqld{,_safe} process running. Use ps(1) and kill(1) if necessary.

Comment: Yes... every time I restart, `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status` says that the server is not running. But when I open the Activity Monitor, there is a `mysqld` process running, which I think is getting in the way.

Comment: never mind what mysql.server status tells you, I think that's only based on the existence of a pid/lock file. Kill the running process, verify using ps(1) that it's not there anymore.

Then and only then can you expect different behaviour from your command to start mysqld.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `ps(1)`. But why do I have to go and kill the process once my computer starts so then it works normal... it should work as soon as the computer starts.

Comment: `Hristo$ ps(1) -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1'`

Comment: ps(1) is a conventional notation for showing that ps is a command whose man page is in section 1.

I agree that you shouldn't _have_ to kill anything, but I was attempting to help you have a working mysqld. You never said whether you had restarted your computer entirely. If you have, then you need to troubleshoot your startup process; you need to determine how this rogue mysqld gets started in the first place and prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed from the DMG, there's a startup script that comes with it, did you double click that?

ok, that script installs stuff in /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM

instead of doing the mysql.server try starting/stopping with that. I know all it's doing is calling mysql.server, but I'm wondering if everything is indeed installed properly or not. The following is copy pasted from the README on the DMG.

If you have installed the Startup Item, use this command:

```
 shell> sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
 (ENTER YOUR PASSWORD, IF NECESSARY)
 (PRESS CONTROL-D OR ENTER "EXIT" TO EXIT THE SHELL)
```

If you don't use the Startup Item, enter the following command sequence:

```
 shell> cd /usr/local/mysql
 shell> sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
 (ENTER YOUR PASSWORD, IF NECESSARY)
 (PRESS CONTROL-Z)
 shell> bg
 (PRESS CONTROL-D OR ENTER "EXIT" TO EXIT THE SHELL)
```

Comment: Of course. I installed the 3 items that come with the DMG... MySQL, the StartupItem, and the Preference Pane item

Comment: This doesn't work either... it says "Starting MySQL" and it thinks for a while, but then nothing.